# Should I put my email server in a public subnet or put in a private subnet and use load balancing / routing to route traffic from the internet?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, email-server, amazon-vpc

I have 3 subnets setup in a Amazon VPC: public, private application, private database.  My web servers are currently in the private application subnet and use a NAT Instance to see the internet.

I need to setup a Win 2012 mail server that will also be used for Jabber and other services.  I was hoping to use the same setup as the application servers so that any websites on the mail server will use a Elastic Load Balancer to add a public address and then I was thinking to add a ENI with public address for the mail IP and a 2nd address for Jabber.

I wanted to keep it more secure by placing it in the private subnet, but if the general rule is to put them in public subnets, then I will consider that.

Answer (score 2):

ELB is good at HTTP and HTTPS, but can be problematic for other protocols..... for complete control over your load balancing / perimeter security, use an haproxy box with a public elastic ip, in combination with ec2 vpc security group rules and host based iptables

Comment: So I would put a HAProxy box in the public subnet of each of my zones and then I could put all my instances in private subnets?

Comment: @Developr thats how i do it :D

Comment: How do you handle high availability with the HaProxy instance?  Ideally I would want to have one of them in each zone, but I am not sure how to achieve a proper failover solution.

Comment: you would want at least two hap's in each zone.... so if your elb has four zones, thats 8 hap's

Comment: Why 2 in each zone?  Is it because I cannot remap IPs between zones/subnets?  How do I setup the HA between zones?  Do I have to use Route53 active/passive load balancing?

Answer (score 0):

The "general" rule is to a a three-tier-architecture.

This is typically suited for web-servers with dynamic content and a database backend.

1. First Tier: Frontend - Webserver - in your case - public IP
2. Second Tier: This is where the work gets done - Application-Server - in your case: e-Mailserver
3. Third Tier: Database - in your case propable storage groups for the mailserver.

In your case the frist tier can contain a load-balancer, a web-application-firewall or just a dedicated firewall.

Comment: Yes, I have 3 tiers... My web servers are in a private subnet with ELB in front.  I am trying to figure out how to get a public IP (non- elb) to point to my mail server in a private subnet.  I think I should be able to do this using ENI with EIP, but it is not working.